# How to parse positional arguments with leading minus sign (negative numbers) using argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I would like to parse a required, positional argument containing a comma-separated list of integers.  If the first integer contains a leading minus ('-') sign, argparse complains:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('positional')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--test', action='store_true')
opts = parser.parse_args()
print opts

$ python example.py --test 1,2,3,4
Namespace(positional='1,2,3,4', test=True)

$ python example.py --test -1,2,3,4
usage: example.py [-h] [-t] positional
example.py: error: too few arguments

$ python example.py --test "-1,2,3,4"
usage: example.py [-h] [-t] positional
example.py: error: too few arguments
```

I've seen people suggest using some other character besides `-` as the flag character, but I'd rather not do that.  Is there another way to configure argparse to allow both `--test` and `-1,2,3,4` as valid arguments?

Comment: Just in case anyone needs this, if --test took argument you could do:

`python example.py --test=-1,2,3,4`

Answer (score 33):

You need to insert a `--` into your command-line arguments:

```
$ python example.py --test -- -1,2,3,4
Namespace(positional='-1,2,3,4', test=True)
```

The double-dash stops argparse looking for any more optional switches; it's the defacto standard way of handling exactly this use case for command-line tools.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of the 'standard' of having to use double-dash (still a *nix newbie of sorts, still learning...)  Thanks for the info!

Comment: That just gives me `error: unrecognized arguments: --` (argparse under Python 2.7.3)

Comment: @panzi: No such problems under Python 2.7.5.

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing):

> The parse_args() method attempts to give errors whenever the user has
>   clearly made a mistake, but some situations are inherently ambiguous.
>   For example, the command-line argument -1 could either be an attempt
>   to specify an option or an attempt to provide a positional argument.
>   The parse_args() method is cautious here: positional arguments may
>   only begin with - if they look like negative numbers and there are no
>   options in the parser that look like negative numbers:

Since `-1,2,3,4` does *not* look like a negative number you must "escape" it with the `--` as in most *nix systems.

An other solution would be to use `nargs` for the positional and pass the numbers as space separated:

```
#test.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('positional', nargs='*') #'+' for one or more numbers

print parser.parse_args()
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py -1 2 3 -4 5 6
Namespace(positional=['-1', '2', '3', '-4', '5', '6'])
```

A third way to obtain what you want is to use `parse_known_args` instead of `parse_args`.
You do not add the positional argument to the parser and parse it manually instead:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--test', action='store_true')

parsed, args = parser.parse_known_args()
print parsed
print args
```

Result:

```
$ python test.py  --test -1,2,3,4                                            
Namespace(test=True)
['-1,2,3,4']
```

This has the disadvantage that the help text will be less informative.

Comment: I saw the documentation, but was wondering if there were any tricks to alter the standard behavior.  At this point, I think it would be better to require four separate positional arguments or use space delimiters than to use the `--` escape mechanism.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Inactivist I updated my answer with a third method to allow `-1,2,3,4` style positional.

Answer (score 0):

I found this from another post somewhere and thought I would update this for the next time I search for how to solve this.

```
$ python example.py --test=-1,2,3,4
```

Should in theory work, it works for me with passing a single entry like

```
$ python example.py --test=-1
```