# Python3.6.6 argparse for negative string values with list of arguments

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm having issues with negative strings being fed into argparse and resulting in errors. I am wondering if anyone has figured out a way around this. Unfortunately, I need the strings to be prepended by a negative sign in some cases, so I cannot fix this by removing the negation part.

I've taken a look at some other stackoverflow pages, such as [How to parse positional arguments with leading minus sign (negative numbers) using argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693718/how-to-parse-positional-arguments-with-leading-minus-sign-negative-numbers-usi) but still have no solution for this. I'm sure that someone must have a solution for this!

Here is what I have tried and am seeing:

```
PyDev console: starting.
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:07:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
import argparse
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# arguments:
argparser.add_argument("--configfile", "--config", type=str, default=None,
                       help="A config file to parse (see src/configs/sample_config.ini for more details).")
argparser.add_argument("--starttime", "--st", type=str, default="-1h@m",
                       help="Starting time for the dump; default: one hour ago rounded to the last minute. \n"
                            "Supported structure: -[0-9]+[h,m,s]+(@[h,m,s])?; for example: -1h@m, -10h, ... OR now")
argparser.add_argument("--endtime", "--et", type=str, default="@m",
                       help="Ending time for the dump; default: current time rounded to the last minute. \n"
                            "Supported structure: -[0-9]+[h,m,s]+(@[h,m,s])?; for example: -1h@m, -10h, ... OR now")
argparser.add_argument("--indexes", "--i", type=str, nargs="+", default="-config-",
                       help="Provide one or more indexes (comma-separated with quotes around the list; "
                            "ex: \"index1, index two, index3\") to search on. Default is \"-config-\" "
                            "which means that the indeces will be gathered from file names; see the sample "
                            "config for details.")
argparser.add_argument("--format", "--f", type=str, default="csv",
                       help="Write data out to CSV file.")
import shlex
args = argparser.parse_args(shlex.split("--configfile /somepath/sample_config_test04.ini --endtime now --indexes \"index one\" index2 index3 --format csv --starttime -5h@m"))
usage: pydevconsole.py [-h] [--configfile CONFIGFILE] [--starttime STARTTIME]
                       [--endtime ENDTIME] [--indexes INDEXES [INDEXES ...]]
                       [--format FORMAT]
pydevconsole.py: error: argument --starttime/--st: expected one argument
Process finished with exit code 2
```

As you can see the above fails, but the following works fine, so I am sure that it's an issue with the "-":

```
PyDev console: starting.
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:07:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
import argparse
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# arguments:
argparser.add_argument("--configfile", "--config", type=str, default=None,
                       help="A config file to parse (see src/configs/sample_config.ini for more details).")
argparser.add_argument("--starttime", "--st", type=str, default="-1h@m",
                       help="Starting time for the dump; default: one hour ago rounded to the last minute. \n"
                            "Supported structure: -[0-9]+[h,m,s]+(@[h,m,s])?; for example: -1h@m, -10h, ... OR now")
argparser.add_argument("--endtime", "--et", type=str, default="@m",
                       help="Ending time for the dump; default: current time rounded to the last minute. \n"
                            "Supported structure: -[0-9]+[h,m,s]+(@[h,m,s])?; for example: -1h@m, -10h, ... OR now")
argparser.add_argument("--indexes", "--i", type=str, nargs="+", default="-config-",
                       help="Provide one or more indexes (comma-separated with quotes around the list; "
                            "ex: \"index1, index two, index3\") to search on. Default is \"-config-\" "
                            "which means that the indeces will be gathered from file names; see the sample "
                            "config for details.")
argparser.add_argument("--format", "--f", type=str, default="csv",
                       help="Write data out to CSV file.")
import shlex
args = argparser.parse_args(shlex.split("--configfile /somepath/sample_config_test04.ini --endtime now --indexes \"index one\" index2 index3 --format csv --starttime 5h@m"))
print(args)
Namespace(configfile='/somepath/sample_config_test04.ini', endtime='now', format='csv', indexes=['index one', 'index2', 'index3'], starttime='5h@m')
```

You may be wondering why I'm calling the code like this; that's because I need to do some unittest-ing of the argparse calls that I am running, so I need to be able to call it from both the commandline as well as from my unittesting code.

If I call the same code from commandline without any quotes or \ in front of the -5h@m, that seems to work fine, but only for commandline (gets converted to \-5h@m). I have tried --starttime \"-5h@m\" and --starttime \-5h@m, -5h@m, '\-5h@m', etc. but nothing seems to be accepted and correctly parsed by argparse other than cmdl input.

The error is typically: 
test.py: error: argument --starttime/--st: expected one argument

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Updates: changing the input to be alike to -configfile=/somepath/sample_config_test04.ini -endtime=now -indexes="index one, index2, index3" -format=csv -starttime=-5h@m seems to work from command line.

NOTE: I'd like to keep this answer mainly because the other suggested answer has a very weirdly phrased title that I would not be have been able to find by doing a google search for what I needed. I did update the question to also reflect that I also had listed items as part of it.

Comment: I'm noticing this line in argparse.py, which I think is the culprit: 
default_prefix = '-' if '-' in prefix_chars else prefix_chars[0]

I'm wondering if there isn't a way to make a prefix more than one char, which should be intuitive... What do you all think?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get argparse to read quoted string with dashes in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174992/cant-get-argparse-to-read-quoted-string-with-dashes-in-it)

Comment: The '-5..' is being parsed as a flag, even though to you it looks like a negative number followed by other characters.  So all the previous discussions of accepting an argument that begins with a dash apply.  The simplest fix is to use `starttime=-5h@m' style of input.

Comment: Quoting the argument with an initial space also works: `--starttime ' -5h@m'`

Comment: I think my main issue is that things that work ok with command line, do not work in code-testing. I tried this: ["bogus","-configfile=/sample_config_test04.ini","-starttime=-5h@m","-endtime=now","-indexes=index1","-format=csv"] to make it look like argv format, but I can't seem to make argparse accept anything of this format. I am completely out of ideas on how to go about testing this via unittest code. Btw, the error that it gives me (very vague): "_jb_unittest_runner.py: error: unrecognized arguments: <list of arguments from above>". Any ideas?

Comment: i'm just going to put a space in front of "-". seems to work fine for testing.