# Special character '-' not read from command line python

Tags: python, python-3.x, special-characters, command-line-arguments, argparse

My python code is as follows:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--cmd_list", nargs="+")
args = parser.parse_args()
cmd_list = args.cmd_list
print(cmd_list)
```

I am aware of the fact that if I need to pass special characters as part of command line arguments, I need to *enclose them within "" or ''*.

As an example the following works [passing $ as an argument]:

```
python3 myfile.py --cmd_list 'sh' '$L'
```

But, encoding '-' within braces does not help.

As an example if I trigger the following:

```
python3 myfile.py --cmd_list 'sh' '-L'
```

I get the following error:

```
error: unrecognised arguments: -L
```

Is there a way to incorporate '-' as a program argument?

Comment: Or [How to parse positional arguments with leading minus sign (negative numbers) using argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693718/how-to-parse-positional-arguments-with-leading-minus-sign-negative-numbers-usi)

Answer (score -1):

Use `sys.argv` to access arguments without processing them, let `file.py` content be

```
import sys
args = sys.argv[1:] # 1st element is file name
print(args)
```

then

```
python3 file.py --cmd_list 'sh' '-L'
```

gives output

```
['--cmd_list', 'sh', '-L']
```

Comment: Yes this works but doesn't make use of *argparse* and also treats *--cmd_list* which ideally needs to be the key to an argument as an argument itself.